# Mail app bug - resents non existing failed emails

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-note-3

My friend has a weird bug on Samsung Note, when he turns on the phone, in his mail app he has 4 messages that marked as failed and it keeps trying to resend them.

When I am trying to navigate to the failed emails I am getting to empty failed mails tab.

This is really killing him, specially when he is abroad and he doesn't has a 3G connection - the phone tries to send those messages (which doesn't exists), so its finishes his battery very quickly..

Any Ideas, except mail app reinstallation, factory reset and such ?

Comment: Is it possible to delete those messages from Mail app? Also, can you tell him to check his email from browser to see if there are outstanding mails/drafts?

Comment: No you cannot delete those messages - cause they doesn't exists in the app. It's 4 emails from last year.  I'll try to check if you can see them from the browser